# Using wp-cli can I not query pages by their title?

Tags: wp-cli

All of these do the same thing:

```
wp post list --post_type=page
wp post list --post_type=page --post_title=dfdsfds
wp post list --post_type=page --title=sdfdsf
```

How can  I query the post by the title? By contrast, using `--name` it works fine:

```
wp post list --post_type=page --name=sdfdsf
```

Answer (score 9):

If we restrict us to the output of `wp post list`, then here's a way to search for `%test%` within the *post titles* of *published* posts:

```
wp post list --ignore_sticky_posts=1 --post__in=$(wp db query 'SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE "%test%" AND post_status="publish" AND post_type="post"' --skip-column-names |  paste -s -d ',' - )
```

Here's the expanded view:

```
wp post list                                 #<-- the first wp command
    --ignore_sticky_posts=1                  #<-- get rid of stickies
    --post__in=                              #<-- only specific post IDs
        $(wp db query                        #<-- the second wp command
            'SELECT ID                       #<-- only get the post IDs
             FROM wp_posts                   #<-- table name, adjust the prefix!
             WHERE post_title LIKE "%test%"  #<-- title search word
               AND post_status="publish"     #<-- published
               AND post_type="post"'         #<-- posts
          --skip-column-names                #<-- Skip the ID column name
          | paste -s -d ',' -                #<-- csv
        )
```

**Update:**

For exact cases, one can replace `post_title LIKE "%test%"` with `post_title = "test"`.

We can use `--skip-column-names` to remove the `ID` column name from the inner query output, instead of using `sed 's/^ID,//'` to remove it. It would be nice if we could use `--format=csv` instead of using `| paste -s -d ',' -`, but currently that doesn't seem to be supported on the `wp db query` command.

There's also the `wp db search` [command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/search/) but currently we can only restrict it to a given table(s), like `wp db search test wp_posts`, but not a given table column. One could e.g. try to play with `wp db search test wp_posts --one_line | grep wp_posts:post_title`, i.e. search the whole `wp_posts` table and filter the output that contains `wp_posts:post_title`, thanks to `--one_line`. But note this is searching the whole table first!

There's also the `wp shell` that prompts the wp-cli shell, where one has access to the WordPress classes and functions, like `WP_Query` and `get_page_by_title()`.

It's also possible to the run `wp eval` [command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval/) and the `wp evail-file` [command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/) to run a given php code. Here's an example: `wp eval 'print_r( get_page_by_title( "test" ) );`

Comment: Upvoting for the extra effort taken to create the expanded view - something we don't see here, but I think that formatting can help in a lot of these Q&A's.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Ran it but got a... ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'mysite-wp-OPSRFxQc.wp_posts' doesn't exist

Comment: @Jay Maybe your table prefix is different from `wp_` ?