# How to delete a single post using wp cli in command line?

Tags: wp-cli

I want delete a single post using wp cli in the command line. There was some issue on one article, where my hosting disabled networking & now want me to remove the article using the console.

I don't know how to do it. Please provide with exact command as in how to locate and delete that post.

Comment: Is this 123 posts ID or post title? Also, how to reach to the post folder or we have to put it directly after successful login with root password

Answer (score 2):

Please read the docs. It's [`wp post delete POST-ID`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/delete/).

> ```
> # Delete post skipping trash
> $ wp post delete 123 --force
> Success: Deleted post 123.
>
> # Delete all pages
> $ wp post delete $(wp post list --post_type='page' --format=ids)
> Success: Trashed post 1164.
> Success: Trashed post 1186.
>
> # Delete all posts in the trash
> $ wp post delete $(wp post list --post_status=trash --format=ids)
> Success: Deleted post 1268.
> Success: Deleted post 1294.
> ```

---

To get posts by title or meta value use `wp post list` and pass the output to `wp post delete` like shown above.

Get posts by title or meta value:

- [WP-CLI How to generate a list of posts with corresponding meta values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/331623/30597)
- [Using wp-cli can I not query pages by their title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/199703/30597)